# Setting WPF stackpanel background color with the same color as contained TextBlock background

Tags: c#, wpf, xaml, binding, .net-3.5

I have a stackpanel that contains an image and a TextBlock.

TextBlock is bound to a style which makes it blink alternating its background color from Red to Black and viceversa.

I would like to bind the TextBlock backgorund color to stackpanel background color, that is, when TextBlock background color is Red I need stackpanel background color to be Red, and when TextBlock background color is Black, then stackpanel background color must change to Black and so on...

Below my code:

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding Path=BlinkOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="auto" Background="Red">
    <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="/My.Images;component/Warning.png" />                    
    <TextBlock x:Name="lblStoryboard"
               TextAlignment="Center"
               Padding="5"                                                         
               Width="Auto"    
               Background="Red"
               Foreground="Black"
               FontSize="12.5"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Style="{StaticResource BlinkingTextBlock}"
               Text="Hi there!" 
               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=BlinkOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    </TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Answer (score -2):

I have solved by binding TextBlock background property to stackpanel background property:

```
<Border Visibility="{Binding Path=BlinkOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}" BorderThickness="1" BorderBrush="Red" CornerRadius="5" Margin="5">
  <StackPanel Orientation="Horizontal" Width="auto">
    <StackPanel.Background>
        <Binding ElementName="txtStoryboard" Path="Background"/>
    </StackPanel.Background>
    <Image Width="24" Height="24" Source="/My.Images;component/Warning.png" />                    
    <TextBlock x:Name="txtStoryboard"
               TextAlignment="Center"
               Padding="5"                                                         
               Width="Auto"    
               Background="Red"
               Foreground="Black"
               FontSize="12.5"
               FontWeight="Bold"
               Style="{StaticResource BlinkingTextBlock}"
               Text="Hi there!" 
               TextWrapping="WrapWithOverflow"
               Visibility="{Binding Path=BlinkOn, Converter={StaticResource BoolToVis}}">
    </TextBlock>
 </StackPanel>
</Border>
```

Comment: Why don't you directly animate the StackPanel's Background and don't set the TextBlock Background at all? This solution looks horrible. There is also no reason to use element syntax for the StackPanel's Background Binding. Write it "as usual": `Background="{Binding Background, ElementName=txtStoryboard}"`.

Comment: @Clemens ok, I will try and tell you if it works. But i am not sure if your solution will work at all by only applying the animation to the stackpanel because maybe the texblock background color is not changing when stackpanel does unless textblock background color is set to transparent.

Comment: The TextBlock's Background has of course to be Transparent or null. And you can of course not ask people to "stop downvoting". It is not "without any reason". Take a downvote as an indication that you did not write a good question or answer, and try to improve it. People don't downvote for fun.